# How do I include VolleyPlus Library in Android studio Project in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to add VolleyPlus library in my android studio project but I still cannot access its classes. I specifically need SimpleMultiPartRequest class of this library.
https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus This is the library on Github.

It is given on the github page that I can just add it in my project gradle like this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
...

dependencies {
     compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
}
...
```

I did it but it still wouldn't work. It is for groovy gradle. I am using kotlin dsl right now.
this my code which I added.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // other repositories...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
        // other dependencies...
        classpath("dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+")
    }
}
```

can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong and give me a solution to my problem.